# Is there a reason to do a cast like this?

Tags: c

I'm working with this large open source C library, and I frequently find casts between types that look like this:

```
char *str;
//some code
unsigned char *str2 = *(unsigned char **) &str;
```

I played around with it, and when I changed it to look like

```
unsigned char *str2 = (unsigned char *) str;
```

It appeared to work without issues.  Note that these casts are frequent throughout the code, used on many types other than unsigned char.

Is there a reason to cast like this by referencing and dereferencing?

**Edit:** I don't know if it is relevant, but this code is supposed to be C89 compliant.

**Edit 2:** Some specific examples

```
void *q = *(void **)(&p[i]);
```

found at: [memento.c](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=mupdf.git;a=blob_plain;f=source/fitz/memento.c;hb=HEAD) (line 1122)

```
unsigned int rgba = *((unsigned int *)color);
```

found at: [draw-paint.c](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=mupdf.git;a=blob_plain;f=source/fitz/draw-paint.c;hb=HEAD) (line 332)

```
return cbz_strnatcmp(*(const char **)a, *(const char **)b);
//both parameters are expected to be const char*
```

found at: [mucbz.c](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=mupdf.git;a=blob_plain;f=source/cbz/mucbz.c;hb=HEAD) (line 73)

Comment: Can you name the library?

Comment: @2501 It is [mupdf](http://mupdf.com/)

Comment: Can you post any links to such examples in actual source code?

Comment: @2501 Sadly, no.  I don't have permission to host any part of their source, and while it is available for free download, I can't find a link directly to any part of a file via web browser.

Comment: Start here: http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=mupdf.git;a=tree;f=source;hb=HEAD

Comment: It's great that you found them, but they have different behavior than the example you presented: `unsigned char *str2 = *(unsigned char **) &str;`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124587/discussion-between-cody-and-2501).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the two alternatives presented involves converting a pointer of one type to a different pointer type via a cast.  This is permitted, including in C89.  In the original code, the converted pointer is explicitly dereferenced; in the revised code it is to be assumed that the pointer will be dereferenced elsewhere.  In these regards, the two variations perform exactly the same kinds of (allowed) behavior.

There is one technical difference, however: the first alternative causes a value of type `char *` to be accessed via an lvalue of type `unsigned char *` when the value of the initialization expression is read so as to be assigned to `str2`.  Those two are not "compatible types" in the standard's sense of that term, nor is the latter an unsigned type corresponding to the former (pointers themselves don't have signedness), nor is the latter a character type or differently-qualifed version of the former, or a union type.  The access therefore violates the provision of the standard colloquially known as the "strict aliasing rule".

The second alternative also converts between incompatible pointer types, but the subsequent accesses it provides for (and that the first alternative also provides for) are allowed by the strict aliasing rule, both because character types can alias anything, and because `unsigned char` is the unsigned type corresponding to `char`, and aliasing between such corresponding types is permitted.

In practice, it's unlikely that any production-ready compiler would do anything with the original code other than what is apparently expected, but your revised code is both cleaner and more correct.

Comment: Casting `char**` to `unsigned char**` is a strict aliasing violation because the strict aliasing rule only allows `char*` types to alias everything? I had the idea that signed-ness didn't matter for strict aliasing.

Comment: @yano, the cast itself is not the violation, and the signedness is not *directly* the problem.  The violation comes when the value of `*(unsigned char **) &str` is accessed, because that expression is an lvalue of type `unsigned char *`, whereas the effective type of the object it designates is actually `char *`.  Character types are allowed to alias anything, but those are not character types, they are (non-compatible) pointer types.  Furthermore, neither is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the other, which would also be allowed.

Comment: @yano, you can access a value whose effective type is `char` via an lvalue whose type is `unsigned char`.  This is explicitly permitted, because the latter is the unsigned type corresponding to the former.  But a conforming program *cannot* access a value whose effective type is `char *` via an lvalue whose type is `unsigned char *`.  Those two types do not have a relationship analogous to the one between the previous two.  In practice, that means you get only one level of indirection out of the "corresponding signed or unsigned type" bit.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to cast like this. Its matter of choice. In case of

```
unsigned char *str2 = *(unsigned char **) &str;
```

there is an unnecessary dereferencing to get the address of character `s` points to.

Using

```
unsigned char *str2 = (unsigned char *)str;
```

looks clean to me.

Comment: The first one is undefined behaviour (as explained by John Bollinger's answer)

Comment: @M.M Thanks. I didn't noticed that before. Will delete this answer.