# Behavior when casting with an extra reference and dereference

Tags: c, casting

[Recently I asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39776984/is-there-a-reason-to-do-a-cast-like-this) about a library I am working with.  I originally asked the question about a specific example, why there was code like `unsigned char *str2 = *(unsigned char **) &str;` instead of having just `unsigned char *str2 = (unsigned char*) str;`, and the answer explained the details of it in the context of `char` to `unsigned char`.

However, in the comments below that question, I was asked for more examples, so I was able to provide a few from the source using other types:

`void *q = *(void **)(&p[i]);`

`fz_colorspace **out_colorspace = (fz_colorspace **)(void *)(&node_ptr[colorspace_off]);`

(There are others that I'm having trouble finding right now, and my regex search skills are weak.  I remember the basic form but can't find a line number, but that can be supplied if someone wants it.)

A comment below my question told me the behavior was going to be different for those types than it was for `char*`->`unsigned char*`, however when I tried to follow up in chat to clarify why that would be, I never received a reply.

**In what ways does casting in this manner (`type2 *b = *(type2**) &a`) differ from the easier approach (`type2 *b = (type2*) a`) in the general case?**  Or, does this only matter on a type by type basis?

Comment: John Bollinger's answer from the other question also answers this question. These are (probably) all undefined behaviour due to violating the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: @M.M 2501's comment under that question implies that there is more to it than that, so I felt I need to clarify.

Comment: Your examples in this question aren't very useful without context. For example if `p[i]` has type `void *` or `const void *`, then that code is correct and equivalent to `void *q = p[i];`.  However if `p[i]` is any other type then it is undefined behaviour.  I think 2501 was suggesting showing more context.

Comment: @M.M that seems reasonable, perhaps I misunderstood.  However, `p[i]` is not `void*`, it is a pointer of another struct type in the library called `fz_display_node*`.  Either way, the answer below clarifies things for me.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(type2*) a` evaluates `a` in whatever type it is and then casts the result to `type2*`.

`*(type2**)&a` takes the address of `a` and reinterprets that address to be one of type `type2**` and then dereferences it. So assuming that the pointer cast goes well,  this interprets the bit pattern of `a` to be the bit pattern of a pointer to `type2`.

All of this is weird stuff, and the latter definitively has undefined behavior. Since `&a` is not of character type, the effecive type rule says that you may not access this object through a different type than its effective type. So derefferencing this pointer is erroneous.

Comment: The extra reference and dereference being erroneous is exactly what I thought.  So to clarify, the only difference is that it has undefined behavior, and will force it to cast whether it is valid or not?

Comment: does your last claim have a citation? according to my memory, c standard allows arbitrary conversion between pointers to data types, and pointers to functions, though not among data types and functions. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Cody, it is undefined behavior, so all arguing stops there. You cannot argue about the state of such  a program that is outside of the rules.

Comment: in 6.3.2.3, c11 draft, `For any qualifier q, a pointer to a non-q-qualified type may be converted to a pointer to
the q-qualified version of the type; the values stored in the original and converted pointers
shall compare equal.` objects your last claim.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr,  sure, the Effective Type Rule is 6.5 p6. Yes, explicit conversion of pointers is allowed, derefferencing them  is not necessarily. *Accessing* objects has to follow the effective type rule. Here the effective type of `a` is `type1`, and `*(type2**)&a` is an lvalue of `type2*`.

Comment: SInce it is undefined behaviour, it's not correct to say that the code interprets a bit pattern differently.  (Actual compilers may or may not realize the undefined behaviour by doing so).

Comment: Your last sentence is nonsense; `&a` is not an object. If you meant "`a` is not of character type", that doesn't matter either: character types may not be accessed through a different type than their effective type either.  (The permitted case is using a character type to access an object with a non-character effective type).